# Using dynamic variables in xpath

Tags: javascript, variables, xpath, greasemonkey

I need a little help with this script:

```
var xpathResult = document.evaluate("(//text()[contains(., 'TEXT GOES HERE')])[1]", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
var node=xpathResult.singleNodeValue;
if (node==null)
```

also I have a list of strings like this:

```
var mycars = new Array();
mycars[0] = "Saab";
mycars[1] = "Volvo";
mycars[2] = "BMW";
```

Can I replace TEXT GOES HERE in the first script with the variable mycars? I'm doing this because I have a dynamically generated page which I want to manipulate with greasemonkey depending on which of the arrays is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question's a little unclear, but in general, you would use a `for()` loop. Something like this:

```
var foundSomething  = false;

for (var J in mycars) {
    var xpathResult     = document.evaluate (
        "(//text()[contains(., '" + mycars[J] + "')])[1]",
        document,
        null,
        XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
        null
    );
    var node            = xpathResult.singleNodeValue;
    if (node) {
        foundSomething  = true;
        // DO WHATEVER WITH THE FOUND NODE HERE.
        // break;  // Un-comment this statement to stop on the first match.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I was asking for. I'm a total noob in programming of any sort and I'm trying to create some scripts which I know what they have to do but have no clue how :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify the string containing the XPath expression to express your requirement in xpath. So in your example, you have to create a string where the multiple condtions are separated by `or`, or you can separate multiple XPath expressions with an `|`. See the examples below:

```
(//text()[contains(., 'Saab') or contains(., 'Volvo') or contains(., 'BMW')])[1]

(//text()[contains(., 'Saab')]|//text()[contains(., 'Volvo')]|//text()[contains(., 'BMW')])[1]
```

Comment: But if the values are dynamic, he'd have to put every possible value in the | clause..

Comment: @JWiley yes, but you can create a function which converts the Array to a string containing the XPath expression.